# ElasticSearch in. python parsing_exception Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [knn]?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Using ElasticSearch 8.12 in python, try to run below query on knn SEARCH based the documentation but get error as title (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/knn-search.html#approximate-knn)

ALL same as the document

```
mappings= {
    "properties": {
      "image-vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 3,
        "index": True,
        "similarity": "l2_norm"
      },
      "title-vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 5,
        "index": True,
        "similarity": "l2_norm"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "file-type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }

body = {
   "knn": {
     "field": "image-vector",
     "query_vector": [-5, 9, -12],
     "k": 10,
     "num_candidates": 100
   },
   "fields": [ "title", "file-type" ]
 }
client.search(index='db-test', body=body)
```

knowing that may need to change the version, tried 8.7, 8.10 and 8.12 python client but all get same error.

Answer (score 0):

When using elasticsearch-py, you need to wrap your knn query inside the body parameter, like this:

```
body = {
  "knn": {
    "field": "image-vector",
    "query_vector": [-5, 9, -12],
    "k": 10,
    "num_candidates": 100
  }
}
client.search(index='db-test', body=body)
```

When using the latest version of elasticsearch-dsl-py (8.12), there is a new `knn()` method that you can leverage, instead of the `search()` method ([official doc](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#k-nearest-neighbor-searches))

```
knn = {
    "field": "image-vector",
    "query_vector": [-5, 9, -12],
    "k": 10,
    "num_candidates": 100
}

s = Search(index="db-test")
s = s.knn(knn)
...
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! However I try two advices above getting same error as usual, noticing that  Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [knn].

Comment: What is the Elasticsearch server version?

Comment: that's the info about server  'version': {
        'number': '7.14.2',
        'build_flavor': 'default',
        'build_type': 'tar',
        'build_snapshot': False,
        'lucene_version': '8.9.0',
        'minimum_wire_compatibility_version': '6.8.0',
        'minimum_index_compatibility_version': '6.0.0-beta1'
    }

Comment: Ah that's it, you're running an old version that didn't have the knn search options. You need to upgrade your server, not only the client